# SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: sql, oracle

Two tables are identical in terms of table name, column names, datatype and size. These tables are located in separate databases, but I am use to 
current Log in in hr user.

```
insert into abc.employees select * from employees where employee_id=100;
```

I can not give use original query from corporate office.

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
insert into abc.employees select * from employees where employee_id=100; 

Error at Command Line:1 Column:25
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 11):

You should specify column names as below. It's good practice and probably solve your problem

```
insert into abc.employees (col1,col2) 
select col1,col2 from employees where employee_id=100;
```

**EDIT**:

As you said `employees` has 112 columns (sic!) try to run below select to compare both tables' columns

```
select * 
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS ATC1
left join ALL_TAB_COLUMNS ATC2 on ATC1.COLUMN_NAME = ATC1.COLUMN_NAME 
                               and  ATC1.owner = UPPER('2nd owner')
where ATC1.owner = UPPER('abc')
and ATC2.COLUMN_NAME is null
AND ATC1.TABLE_NAME = 'employees'
```

and than you should upgrade your tables to have the same structure.

Comment: Not is possible because original tables in 112 columns and work on large table 800+ so ..................

Comment: `employees` table has 112 columns !?

Comment: @user2703444 I've forgot `AND ATC1.TABLE_NAME = 'employees'` condition :), try it now please

Comment: Usually, Oracle object / schema names are in uppercase (unless explicitly quoted on creation time), so I guess this should be "ATC1.owner = 'ABC'" / "ATC1.TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES'".

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Right! I've added `upper` function

Comment: So if the original question was missing the column names, why was the error `ORA-00913: too many values`?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Probably the destination table had less columns then in select. So in select was too many values.

Comment: *"Not is possible because original tables in 112 columns and work on large table 800+ "*  Of course it's possible, it just is a bit of hard work. This is the price paid for poor table design. (Granted, the person paying the price probably isn't responsible for the data model.)

Comment: Also when `SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:` - this error arises, the same solution of explicitly mentioning works.

Answer (score 7):

The 00947 message indicates that the record which you are trying to send to Oracle lacks one or more of the columns which was included at the time the table was created.
The 00913 message indicates that the record which you are trying to send to Oracle includes more columns than were included at the time the table was created.
You just need to check the number of columns and its type in both the tables 
ie the tables that are involved in the sql.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the `insert` statement was missing one column, and so in `select`, I had one additional value. Adding the missing column in the insert statement fixed the error for me.

Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having 112 columns in one single table and you would like to insert data  from source table, you could do as

```
create table employees as select * from source_employees where employee_id=100;
```

Or from sqlplus do as

```
copy from source_schema/password insert employees using select * from 
source_employees where employee_id=100;
```

Comment: It will create tabel with only one row, what will you do if you want to copy next to to the same table?

Comment: @Parado What ever rows satisfies where condition will be copied to target table.

Comment: But if OP's want to copy data every day, every week ?

Comment: @Parado Where does OP specifies that he would copy data every week?

Comment: @Parado Not sure what exactly you are referring or mentioned. OP has to decide what he wants to do Period.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works perfect

```
insert into oehr.employees select * from employees where employee_id=99
```

I am not sure why you get error. The nature of the error code you have produced is the columns didn't match.

One good approach will be to use the answer @Parodo specified

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit late.. but i have seen this problem occurs when you want to insert or delete one line from/to DB but u put/pull more than one line or more than one value ,

E.g:

you want to delete one line from DB with a specific value such as id of an item but you've queried a list of ids then you will encounter the same exception message.

regards.